# Real-time SSH output in Laravel with phpseclib

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, real-time, phpseclib

I've tried different SSH libraries but they don't seem to work too well in Laravel. Since I got phpseclib to work well, I'm trying to stick with it. But, I'm not seeing a way to have a live output from the SSH connection.

Some things that I plan on running can take up to a few hours to finish but the software being accessed always prints out a percentage of completion that I'd like to utilize to display in the browser.

Currently, I have this:

```
    <?php

    use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
    use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

    $key = new RSA();
    $key->loadKey(file_get_contents('key.pem'));

    $command = 'ping google.com';

    $ssh = new SSH2('awesomeserver.com');

    if (!$ssh->login('username', $key))
    {
        echo 'Login Failed';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $ssh->exec($command);
    }

    ?>
```

This just waits until the command is complete and then just barfs it all onto the screen.

Previously, in the `else` bracket, I had
        while(@ ob_end_flush());

```
    $proc = $ssh->exec($command);

    while(!feof($proc))
    {
        echo fread($proc, 4096);
        @ flush();
    }
```

But, `$proc` was only recognized as a string instead of a resource, so it didn't work.

Do you all have any other suggestions, other than using a different library?

Thanks!

EDIT (Partial solution):

I eventually got this script to work by utilizing the `read()` function with this:
        while(@ ob_end_flush());

```
    $ssh->write($command.'\n');

    while($read = $ssh->read())
    {
        echo $read;
        @ flush();
    }
```

Comment: Your partial solution works for me as well except that it takes about 10 secs between each echo and the loop while quit if nothing has output since the last echo. I tried to set `$ssh->setTimeout(1)` but then it quits the loop as soon as nothing has been outputted within that second. I wonder how you could make it check every 1 or 2 seconds and not quit the loop until it's all said and done...  Maybe check for the prompt in the loop condition...

Answer (score 1):

You could employee a callback. eg.

```
$ssh->exec('ping 127.0.0.1', function($output) {
    echo $output;
});
```

Comment: I did that. Unfortunately, it waits until the the full response is given before it outputs. As I'm running programs that run for hours, giving updates every few seconds, I would just get a timeout error with this.

Comment: @Cod-nerd - `flush()` / `ob_flush()` might help but ultimately this would depend on the webserver you're using (Apache, nginx, etc), the SAPI you're using (CGI, Apache module, etc), etc.

Comment: That doesn't work with the `exec()` function. But, it did work with the `read()` function. But, my server times out the script now. Lol! That's fine, though. I shouldn't have a PHP script run for that long anyways.